# Make auto fill form a part of table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, formula, excel-2021

I have a table (table1) then is my data table same as below
[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc77e.png)

and I have a form then that have a table inside it same as below
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KAXr.png)

I need when I enter the "POD" from "Table1" in "POD"(B1) in "Form", the "Table2"(inside "Form") fill by data from "Table1". this may 1 row or multi row data. and I don't need all columns from "Table1"

Thanks for your solution
Best Regards

I try Xlookup , match, find, filter and anything I know
but I didn't find anything

Comment: What's the version you tried using `FILTER`? What did it return versus what you expected it to return?

Comment: @P.b  I'm using 2021. did u see picture? I tried FILTER but :(

Comment: @P.b I need any columns of data. but FILTER return all columns

Comment: So you answered what it returned, what you expected from it, but not what the formula was you used. And yes I did see the picture, but I'm surprised you say your formula returned all, since you're using a table which doesn't allow spilling. Therefore, be more descriptive and we can help.

Comment: for example i need this colomns: A , B , D , F. they are not stacked together. when i want to select them, excel reject it.

Comment: Please update your question (using edit) to include your formula you tried (especially the one using FILTER). And explain what it returned and what you expected it to return.